# IndexError: index 69791 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 56044

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflearn, conv-neural-network

```
def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data

train_data = create_train_data()

train = train_data[:-500]
test = train_data[-500:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

**Getting following error**


Traceback (most recent call last):
Training samples: 168132
Validation samples: 1500
--
  File "C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Anas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anas\PycharmProjects\Minorproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Anas\PycharmProjects\Minorproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Anas\PycharmProjects\Minorproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
IndexError: index 69804 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 56044
```

I have all the images of 32X32 pixels RGB images(4 Band). I am getting the above error. I don't know why it is getting out of bound, isn't it because of too many images?
Does anyone have any idea how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reshaping it incorrectly . You want to laod ARGB image but you are reshaping X as `reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)` instead you should do `reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,4)` for 4 channel image, and same to your test_x variable .

Edited Part of Code :

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,4)
test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,4)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, I have 4 bands, so I put (-1,32,32,4) but when I am reshaping my original test data in the same way as above  which has the exact same type of images as training data, it is showing this error, ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 112640 into shape (-1,32,32,4). 
Should I delete some images to make 112640 exact divisible by 32*32*4?

Comment: By deleting Images it still not gonna work. I think you should check if it is really 4 band images

Comment: yes, it has 4 bands, ref: https://www.kaggle.com/fedebayle/slums-argentina 
Can you explain me for 3 bands why I need to reshape my array as array.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)?